# Is it possible for GNOME keyring / Seahorse to show the plaintext password for a GPG key?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gnupg, gnome-keyring

I have a GPG key which has stopped decrypting with a "Bad passphase" error when used from the command line.

While I'm fairly confident the passphase is correct, as I've typed it at least once per work day for year, I want to be sure.

The passphase is actually stored in GNOME keyring (Seahorse) so I can decrypt if I boot in to GNOME. For context I usually use i3 window manager which does not load GNOME keyring.

Is there a way to get GNOME keyring to show me the plain text passphase?

- Ubuntu 19.04
- Seahorse 3.32

Answer (score 1):

- Open "Passwords and Keys" (Seahorse).
- Click on "Logins" in the "Passwords" section on the left
- Enter user password if prompted
- Right click on the GPG key and choose Properties
- Press Copy to the right of the Password input